# Check the convergence of series ∑ x^n 3^n/n! And find the interval of convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I already checked the convergence using d'Alembert test but I am not sure how to find the interval. 
Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x\\\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3x)^n}{n!}=e^{3x}
$$and radius of convergence tends to $\infty$ 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(3x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(3x)^n}{n!}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|{\frac{(3x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n!}{(3x)^n}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|{\frac{3x}{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|3x|}{n+1}\\ \to 
|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|3x|}{n+1}|<1 \implies x \in \mathbb{R}$$as a second hint remeber $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \to |x|<1\\or \\\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(kx)^n \to |kx|<1 \to |x|<\frac{1}{|k|},radisus= \frac{1}{|k|}$$

Comment: From this the answer should be e^3x but from ratio test, I am getting 3x/n+1, why?

Comment: @kiv: you are right because of this limitation tends to zero, so the radius of convergence tends to $\infty$

Comment: Note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3|x|}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3|x|}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the ratio test to prove that the series converges for each $x\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, the interval of convergence is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: After doing the ratio test, I got 3x/n+1, how should I explain the rest?

Comment: Actually, you should apply it the the series of the absolute values. Then you get $\frac{3\lvert x\rvert}n$. Now, you use the fact that, for each $x\in\mathbb R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\lvert x\rvert}n=0$.